# How to change owner of folder to current user recursively?

Tags: permissions, ownership

Using `sudo nautilus` I created some folders and I want to get rid of root permission on them. But I have many and I want to do it to a entire directory and its containing folders.

So how to allow read/write to current user to all files and folders inside a specific directory that is inside `/home`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To revert damage done using `sudo nautilus` you should make yourself the owner of any directories (and their contents) that are owned by root.

You can use `find` to do this, as it has a test to find only files owned by a specific user.

This will find all the directories in your home owned by root:

```
sudo find ~ -type d -user root
```

You can then repeat the `find` command and add the action you want to do - recursively changing ownership of all the found directories and their contents to the current user:

```
sudo find ~ -type d -user root -exec sudo chown -R $USER: {} +
```

#### Explanation:

- `~` the home directory
- `-type d` find only directories
- `-user root` find only stuff belonging to root
- `-exec` do the following command on whatever was found
- `sudo chown -R` recursively change owner
- `$USER` the current user
- `:` also change group to the specific user

More efficiently, you could omit the `-type d` to find files of any type belonging to root, and also omit the `-R` as `find` will do the recursion for you by acting on all the files

```
sudo find ~ -user root -exec sudo chown $USER: {} +
```

Answer (score 24):

Running GUI tools, like `nautilus` as `root` is Considered Harmful for this reason, among others (hidden functions, ability to silently run program fragments from who knows where, ...).

You don't have a "permission" problem, you have an "ownership" problem.

To find all the files owned by `root` (really owned by anybody else), do:

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER
```

To change the ownership back to you, you could

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME
```

but that will change the ownership of all files in and under `$HOME`

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER >/tmp/list-of-files
# edit the list of files, and delete file files you don't want to chown
nano /tmp/list-of-files 
xargs sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) </tmp/list-of-files
```

Gives one the opportunity to adjust the list of files, owned by not-you, that will have their ownership changed back to you.

Answer (score 12):

What you need to do is change the ownership of the folder from the user (and group) *root* to the other user (and group) you want.

Imagine you want to work on */home/randomFolder*, and that the user you want to handle ownership to is *vitor-abella*, what you need to do is simply execute this as root:

```
chown -R vitor-abella:vitor-abella /home/randomFolder
```

It may take a while if there's a lot of files and subfolders, but after that you should be on track.

Cheers.

Comment: I use `$(id -u):$(id -g)`, rather than asking O.P. to imagine, and `$HOME/randomFolder`.